вылетает ошибка Unhandled Rejection : ReferenceError: Intents is not defined
Вот собственно код, который по команде /ping должен присылать информацию о сервере.
к сожалению он выдает мне ошибку  Unhandled Rejection : ReferenceError: Intents is not defined. пытался исправить ее в итоге вышел на новую ошибку: Unhandled Rejection : ReferenceError: client is not defined
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const minecraftProtocol = require('minecraft-protocol');

const client = new Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});

const botPrefix = '/';
const botToken = 'YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN'; // Замените на свой собственный токен

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // игнорировать сообщения от других ботов
    if (!message.content.startsWith(botPrefix)) return; // игнорировать сообщения без префикса

    const args = message.content.slice(botPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        try {
            const serverInfo = await getServerInfo('IP_OF_SERVER', SERVER_PORT);
            message.channel.send(serverInfo);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.channel.send('Ошибка при получении информации о сервере');
        }
    }
});

async function getServerInfo(host, port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        minecraftProtocol.ping({ host, port }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject('Невозможно подключиться к серверу');
            } else {
                const version = res.version.name;
                const playersOnline = `${res.players.online}/${res.players.max}`;
                const tps = 'N/A'; // Замените на реальное значение TPS, если у вас есть соответствующий плагин
                resolve(`Сервер: ${host}:${port}\nВерсия: ${version}\nИгроки: ${playersOnline}\nTPS: ${tps}`);
            }
        });
    });
}

client.login(botToken);


Добро пожаловать на сайт,亗Ꭺᴠᴛᴀʀɪᴛᴇᴛ 亗, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

вы этот скрипт так и запускаете, без подстановки botToken, IP_OF_SERVER, SERVER_PORT?

Переводить ошибку в переводчике пробовали? На смотреть на то место, где возникла ошибка и выше по коду искать, почему переменная не объявлена. Регистр тоже важен

@nörbörnën скрипт запускаю подставляя данные, к сожалению т.к. токен дискор бота является конфиденциальной информацией, я не могу его предоставить

@SwaD я читал об этой ошибке и о других. к особому выводу не пришел.

в источнике этого скрипта должен быть файл package.json, скопируйте его в проект, установите модули повторно и попробуйте запустить

@nörbörnën могу вставить код этого файла, однако код этого файла не трогал

дайте ссылку на репозиторий

@nörbörnën хорошо, сейчас перенесу все файлы в новый репозиторий

четко же написано - переменная не определена. А значит вероятно из-за каких-то обновлений уже по-другому нужно делать. Для 14 версии - Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE не актуально. Вот об этом написано на stackoverflow.com https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/11108892

@Arbery ну да. по этому проще узнать какая версия discord.js используется в исходниках программы и запускать под ней всё хозяйство

@nörbörnën ну значит задавшему вопрос - даунгрейд node и скрипта или читать документацию как по-новому делать.

не хотелось бы переделывать весь скрипт, т.к. он сейчас работал идеально кроме самой команды /ping

общий смысл такой: вы скопировали код из репозитория похожего на этот https://github.com/flameface/minecraft-wiki-bot, для начала вам нужно скопировать оттуда package.json и package-lock.json, удалить каталог node_modules и попробовать установку библиотек командой npm ci. возможно оно взлетит, а если нет то нужно учиться программировать, чтобы заставить это работать
